# wpf app: help files with search and index

Tags: wpf, search, indexing, chm

We are adding help files to our WPF application in Visual Studio 2010. We have not been able to find so far a method that we have been able to use.

We have some HTML help files, currently they are just in a directory, not added to the WPF project.

We don't have index or search.

I have seen that maybe we can do something with cmh, but this seems quite old and outdated now.

Ideally we would like all this in WPF, but if its not possible we need another solution.

We would like to be able to hit F1, have our main help page displayed (we have this now, it opens in our browser) and additionally add Index and Search to our main help page.

Can anyone point us in the right direction please?

Comment: A more contemporary approach, i.e., Windows 7 and up, has jump lists that you can configure.  Did you look in to that possibility?

Comment: Your post is tagged CHM, could you please explain better why you did that. Do you have CHM's, do you want to make them from raw html?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) Method page on MSDN. In particular, the [Process.Start Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) page has a code example showing how to open web pages from a WPF application.

To do this *inside* a WPF application, look at the [WebBrowser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) page at MSDN. This also provides a code example of loading a web page into your application.

EDIT >>> After re-reading your post, I realise that I missed the bit about searching and indexing. Surely, you can just search through the web pages yourself? Just open each page and use something like

```
if (webPageContent.Contains(searchTerm)) return webPageContent;
```

Comment: Since his post is tagged "chm" you probably should read "html help files" as "htmlhelp files", iow CHM.